# How can I load different images for mobile with Slick Slider?

Tags: image, mobile, slider, slick.js

I try to create mobile version of slick slider (it should display different images on mobile).

Is it any simple way to do that without adding second time very similar code with changes image src or I should build next div slider and hide/show on mobile version.

Comment: Just use picture element in combination with media queries on the source items: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me. It's using lazy loading and media query with image specification based on correct screen size. Also picture tag is used. Doesn't seem to be slow to load.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var slider = $('#slider');
        var total = $('#slider img').length, // get the number of slides
            rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * total); // random number        
        slider.slick({
            lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
            dots: true,
            infinite: true,
            speed: 0,
            fade: true,
            cssEase: 'linear',
            autoplay: true,
            pauseOnDotsHover: true,
            autoplaySpeed: 7000
        });
        slider.slick('slickGoTo', rand);  // navigate to random slide;       
        slider.slick('slickSetOption', 'speed', 1000);  
    });
    
    $('#slider').on('lazyLoaded', function(evt) {
        $(evt.currentTarget).find('source').each(function(i, source) {
            var $source = $(source);
            $source.attr('srcset', $source.data('lazy-srcset'));
        });
    }); 
</script>

<div class="lazy slider_inner" id="slider" data-sizes="50vw"> 
    <div class="slide_holder">
        <div class="slide_inner">
            
            <picture>
                <source data-lazy-srcset="img/RotatingBannersSquare-Base.jpg" media="(max-width: 767px)">
                <img data-lazy="img/RotatingBanners-Base.png" alt="">
            </picture>

            <div class="slide_content">
                <h2 class="group-heading">
                    THE COMPLETE PACKAGE
                </h2>
                <p class="group-text">
                    From head-to-toe we have you covered!<br />
                    We have the gear to keep you playing longer,<br />
                    training harder and performing better.
                </p>
                <div style="padding-top:5px;"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs button-rounded">SHOP BASEBALL</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--slide_holder-->
    <div class="slide_holder">
        <div class="slide_inner">

            <picture>
                <source data-lazy-srcset="img/RotatingBannersSquare-CS.jpg" media="(max-width: 767px)">
                <img data-lazy="/img/RotatingBanners-CS.png" alt="">
            </picture>
            
            <div class="slide_content slide_content_left">
                <h2>COVID-19 Prevention</h2>
                <p>Protect yourself and others around. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a little touch of js

js

```
let imgs = [
  '<img class="desktop" src="./assets/joursHardtopImage.png"/>',
  '<img class="desktop" src="./assets/joursHardtopImage.png"/>',
]
let mobileImgs = [
  '<img class="mobile" src="./assets/joursMobileImage.png"/>',
  '<img class="mobile" src="./assets/joursMobileImage.png"/>',
]

if($( window ).width() < 600){
  for (let i = 0; i < mobileImgs.length; i++) {
    $('.carousel').append(mobileImgs [i])
  }
}else{
   for (let j = 0; j < imgs.length; j++) {
    $('.carousel').append(imgs[j])
  }


//carousel section

$('.carousel').slick({
  speed: 1000,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  prevArrow: '<button class="slide-arrow prev-arrow"></button>',
  nextArrow: '<button class="slide-arrow next-arrow"></button>', 
 });
```

html

```
<div class="carousel">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it with simple media queries, like to add two images to each slide and use CSS media query to show the right image.

Example code below.

HTML

```
<div class='my-slide'>
  <div class='item'>
    <img src='myImageMobile.jpg' alt='me' class='item-img-mobile'>
    <img src='myImage.jpg' alt='me' class='item-img-desktop'>
  </div>
  <div class='item'>
    <img src='myImageMobile2.jpg' alt='me' class='item-img-mobile'>
    <img src='myImage.jpg2' alt='me' class='item-img-desktop'>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.item-img-desktop {
  display: none;
}

@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
  .item-img-desktop {
    display: block;
  }

  .item-img-mobile {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Of course, you can use `<picture>` tag instead the wrapper div.

Comment: This solution forces browser to load two both images at once which is terrible for performance, especially on cellular connection.